# chrt set process to SCHED_OTHER policy failed with "Invalid argument"

Tags: linux

During my work, i want set the schedule policy of one process from SCHED_FIFO to SCHED_OTHER for debug purpose. But i got follow errors. Is chrt command only support real-time schedule policy setting? Or is there some other reason? Thanks in advance.

[root@BB-0(vBTS-1) /tmp]

## chrt -p -o 5 2827

pid 2827's new scheduling policy: SCHED_FIFO
pid 2827's new scheduling priority: 10
chrt: can't set pid 2827's policy: Invalid argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chrt command sets/modifies the static priority value of the process. For SCHED_OTHER, the only allowed static priority value is 0, ie. the -o option must be followed by 0.
The nice level of a SCHED_OTHER process can be adjusted with renice command